# Browser prompts client certificates only from current user store ignoring local machine store

Tags: windows, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509

I've implemented an application, which installs X509 client certificates on the user's computer. They are supposed to be used to log in to the SSO system. They are installed both in the context of current user and local machine.

The problem is when the user is trying to log in and the server asks for the client certificate, all the browsers prompt only the certificates from current user store, even if launched as an Administrator. It can be seen here:

[image: current user vs local machine]

Certificates from the local machine store are ignored by the browser. Is there any way for the browser to consider them? Otherwise, what is the purpose of Personal certificates in the context of local machine, if not used in cases like this?

Comment: Local machine certificate store is used to create the local user certificate store when the user is created

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. But is it possible to install the certificate in the context of local machine after all the accounts are created and use it as a client certificate from these accounts?

Comment: The goal is to install certificate only once per machine and use it regardless of which user is currently logged in.

Comment: @dradzikowski I'm in the same position. I'm unable to get browsers to use the local machine certificate store for certificate authentication. Did you figure out how to make this work?

Comment: I'm on this same error. Did any of you discover how to fix it? @Appleoddity

Comment: @Jimmy No. Chrome and Firefox don’t use the computer’s certificate store and won’t authenticate with SSO and multi-factor auth to services like Office 365. Microsoft has a plugin for Chrome that solves the problem for Office 365. Alternatively Internet Explorer and Edge will use the machine certificate store. I’m not aware of any changes to that since this message posted.

Comment: @Jimmy PS we got around it by using always on VPN and bypassing multi-factor auth for “on premise” systems that included VPN connected devices.